# Javascript / PHP / JSON : Update the select input depending on a first select

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json, select

I'm working on a form, asking for some informations about how many children someone can have, and how old they are. The goal is to show, depending on the number of the first select (number of children), the correct number of select for their age.

I've got a PHP file where I get the content of my JSON file (where the question are) which create the correct input depending on a attribute into the JSON file (for ex: "criteria_type" = "select", the PHP will create a select input).

The PHP code looks like that :

```
if($grp_critere['crt_type'] == 'select') {

    $html_grp_criteres = '<select name="'. $grp_critere['crt_id'].'|scq_'.$grp_critere['question_key'].'" onchange="change_select_number">'.$html_grp_criteres.'</select>';
}
```

The issue is that I have to show only the select I need, if the person choose 3 children, 3 select input with the age choice will appear.

So I created two types of "crt_type" for the different types of select:

1. select_origine : the first one which change the number of the next select input
2. select_update : the select who depend of the number chosen

Any idea in Javascript with the onchange function or .change in Jquery to make it possible ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create a div to be the container for your extra select elements (I'll give it "input_container" as an id for this example).

I'm also giving the initial selection box (number of children) an id of "selection".

Based on your code, #selection already fires a change_select_number function when it's changed, so this is all you need to do:

```
function change_select_number(){
    if($("#selection").val() > $("#input_container").children().length){ // if we need to add fields
        num = $("#selection").val() - $("#input_container").children().length; // find out how many elements we need to add
        for(i=0;i<num;i++){
            $("#input_container").append("<select style='display:block;' name='select_update["+$("#input_container").children().length+"]'><option>1<option>2</select>"); // add a select as a child of #input_container
        }
    }else if($("#selection").val() < $("#input_container").children().length){  // if we need to remove fields
        num = $("#input_container").children().length - $("#selection").val(); // find out how many elements to remove
        for(i=0;i<num;i++){
            $("#input_container select:last-child").remove(); // remove the last select from #input_container
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot to take time!

It helps me to see which behavior my select have to get, but the remain issue is that my select with the ages are already created in the JSON and imported with the PHP.

So in the "for", I won't have to make and "append" of the number of select, just have to get (or display, simply) the select_update.

Wishing be understood